# Angular2 instance bound methods does not work as hooks

Tags: angular

Implemented ngOnInit() hook by using instance bound method and it stoped working....

Simplified example:

```js
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';

  @Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>'
  })
  export class AppComponent { 
    name = 'Angular'; 
    
    ngOnInit = () => {
      this.name = 'World';
    }
  }
```

expected result => "Hello World"
real result => "Hello Angular"

Is it described somewhere that exactly that methods are disallowed to be used exactly for hooks? Or what is the problem w/ using them as such?

Live example: https://plnkr.co/edit/aZ1CYkDn06KUENmDW3a3?p=preview

**IMPORTANT:** Question is not how to fix. I know that i could change to `ngOnInit() {}`. The question is - *why instance bound method does not work as a hook*

**FOLLOW UP** Created an issue in the Angular repo - to improve behavior / docs / error notifications: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16478 guess there will be more clear answer. Will post it here after it will be clear / confirmed that behavior is by design checking the class prototypes only.

Comment: I've edited my answer to properly address your issue

Comment: @echonax thx, but the real question is not to make it work :) Q is - why it does not work w/ instance bound methods. I kinda like a convention to use instance bound methods for all the classes, but unpredictable angular behavior is against it. Thx for helping tho!

Comment: It shouldn't work because as I've said all you are doing is creating a function declaration. It is not bound to anything like a prototype which `ngOnInit` actually is.

Comment: @echonax ah, interesting. Angular will not invoke any hooks that are declared per-instance, not on a prototype of it? Is there any docs mentioning that? Assuming that is for performance or so, but havnt seen any info about that.

Answer (score 4):

It should be

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.name = 'World';
}
```

Think of it like you are overriding the default cycle

Fixed plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/DGkNulwYs4WpYULhl9gD?p=preview

Note:

Implementing the life-cycle hooks are optional as it says in the documentation. Because javascript doesn't have interfaces

Source: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#interface-optional

**Edit**:

What you are doing is just creating a function inside your component which is named `ngOnInit` if you want to execute it you have to do it somewhere inside your component. The best place to do it seems like the constructor:

```
constructor(){
    this.ngOnInit();    
}
```

Fixed plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/NAHX5vfoMXtN95Y0oyOR?p=preview

**Edit2:**

Here's the proof of the prototype:

With the way you do it, the function will **not** be a part of the prototype chain of the component base class (line 17):
[image: function]

But this way Angular will see it as a part of the prototype chain (line 15):
[image: prototype]

Comment: Yep, it is correct syntax, but i would like to use class bound one to not care about the context afterwards.

We are considering to switch to class bound convention for all methods we have - which will be less error-pron. But this Angular behavior prevents us from doing that...

Comment: Downvoted this answer as it doesn't address the OP's question.

Comment: @jessepinho thanks for the feedback, I'll check for a proper solution

Comment: @jessepinho btw do you think other answers address the OP's question?

Comment: @echonax thx for the note about per-instance method. Would be nice to find any proofs why is it behaving like that (perf issues or so). But now it is kinda clear what is going on there

Comment: @InviS I'm going through the source code for further info. And I was going to show you a code snippet on typescript playground but apparently there's a bug on the site :-) I'll edit my answer as soon as they fix it

Comment: @echonax yep was also going to post link from playground, but it is broken ATM :) reported it via Gitter already :D

Comment: @echonax i got that already :) asked about explanation / help on github => https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16478 Smth definitely could be improved there - at least docs

Answer (score 2):

Add the implements and change the ngOnInit like echonax say:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

  @Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>'
  })
  export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    name = 'Angular'; 

    ngOnInit() {
      this.name = 'World';
    }
  }
```

Comment: `implements` has been changed to `extends` with angular4, fyi

Comment: its another way around. they deprecated extend in favor of implements. Dont assume they promoted extend syntax somewhere anyway

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly declare that the component implements OnInit and fix the function implementation syntax:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit { 
    public ngOnInit(): void {
       this.name = 'World';
    }
}
```